# compile masstree from source in riscv64

Tags: linux, makefile, g++, fedora, riscv

i am running a container in docker, and the image is https://hub.docker.com/r/imbearchild/fedora-rv64

recently, i try to compile opengauss from source, and i have some problems compiling opengauss-third_party. masstree is a part of opengauss-third_party.

when i run sh build.sh, i find that "g++: error: unrecognized command-line option '-mcx16'"

i konw that '-mcx16' is a g++ option in x86_64, so i read the Makefile in masstree source code, and i find that

```
ifeq ($(shell uname -p),aarch64)
        CXXFLAGS += -march=armv8-a+crc
else
        CXXFLAGS += -mcx16
endif
```

yes, there are aarch64(-march=armv8-a+crc) and x86_64(-mcx16), so it is not surprise to find error in riscv.

my english and the knowledge in riscv are poor ,i am sorry about that.

i want to know ,is there a similar option in riscv64 to satisfy masstree.

i don't want to simply delete this option but rather want to find an alternative